# Why does the offset of a linked duplicated array modifier change?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

Number of modifiers are the same, value for relative offset is set to z +1.00

**Expected result:** 
When I alt + D to duplicate the object with modifiers the height of the offset items will be the same.

**Observed result:** 
After alt+D the number of items, the number of modifiers applied and all the modifier values are duplicated correctly, but the actual distance between each item is not correct on the duplicate objects

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** 
I made one window and I'm trying to apply it to the whole building, using array modifier and shrinkwrap modifier.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your scene. Could you provide a blend file? Check the scale of your object, clear or it or apply it. Also consider using absolute values for offset instead of relative ones, may yield more precise results

Comment: This is probably the shrinwrap modifier which moves your windows depending of the part of the target object they are on. What is the role of the shrinkwrap here ?

Comment: To Get all the windows to fit perfectly against the building I couldn't think of a better way to do it I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: You should build your windows out of the same mesh instead of making them separate and then trying to fit them in. Only exact measurements will really work well, and modifiers tend to change things so that needs to be taken into consideration. I find that building things the way you're doing leads to starting over again and again because of little problems like this. Pre-planning is very important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a little difficult to tell what's going on, even with the image, but I'll take a stab at it.

I think you're seeing an interaction between the shrinkwrap modifier and the array modifier. It's a little complicated, so I'll try to be clear.

The *relative* offset will move the next item in the array by a multiple of that item's own size. In your case, it moves "the item's z height * 1.0" So, if your item's height were to change, the next item in the list would still be exactly on top of it, because it's moving "one item's height." If you change that multiple to anything bigger than 1, you'll have a gap.

This works fine when each version of your array is the same. BUT you have a shrinkwrap modifier, which can change the size and shape of your mesh, if it needs to. It looks like your shrinkwrap is "reaching" to wrap itself to the nearest thing it can find. This makes your mesh bigger. Now "one item height" is much bigger than it used to be. Now it has to offset a lot more on the z-axis to get the next item ontop of the previous one.

To test this, change the windows that are working from relative offset to absolute offset. Find an absolute offset amount that gets those windows stacked correctly. Then change the other windows to absolute, and use the same amount. If I'm right, you should see all the windows stacking correctly.

Unfortunately, I don't think this will solve your problem. The real solution will be to get your shrinkwrap under control so that it's behaving correctly. If you fix that, then you can use relative or absolute and get the same result.

Comment: makes perfect sense.

Comment: Of course it does ;-) But does it solve your problem?